# Change of Basis In Matrix Form

Tags: matrices, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

Suppose $S_1, S_2,$ and $S_3$ are three bases for $ℝ^3$ and base transition matricies $_{S1}T_{S2}$ and $_{S1}T_{S3}$ are (respectively)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&&3&&-1\\
1&&0&&-2\\
0&&-3&&5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&&-3&&1\\
4&&6&&0\\
8&&0&&-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How would one compute $_{S2}T_{S3}$?

Comment: I'm assuming $_{S1}T_{S2}$ is the transition from $S_2$ to $S_1$ and so on.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Isn't notation a pain?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vector space $E$ endowed with bases $S_1, S_2, S_3$, $_{S_i}T_{S_j}$ is the matrix of the identity map from $(E,S_j)$ to $(E, S_i)$ and its inverse is the matrix of the identity map the other way. Now if you consider the commutative diagram:
\begin{array}{rcl}
(E, S_2)&\xrightarrow[_{S_2}T_{S_3}]{=} &(E, S_3) \\
=\searrow&\enspace\scriptstyle\llap{{}_{S_2}T_{S_1}}\quad_\rlap{{}_{S_1}{\scriptstyle T} _{S_3}}, &\nearrow=\\[]
&(E, S_1)
\end{array}
you obtain instantly
$$_{S_2}T_{S_3}={}_{S_1}T_{S_3}{\,}_{S_2}T_{S_1}={}_{S_1}T_{S_3}{\,}_{S_1}T_{S_2}^{-1}$$

Comment: I'm assuming $_{S1}T_{S2}$ is the transition from $S_2$ to $S_1$ and so on.

Comment: I have the inverse convention from yours?

Comment: Yes it seems that we have two different notation!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- $v_1=_{S1}T_{S2}\cdot v_2 \implies v_2=(_{S1}T_{S2})^{-1}\cdot v_1$
- $v_1=_{S1}T_{S3}\cdot v_3$

then

$$v_2=(_{S1}T_{S2})^{-1}\cdot_{S1}T_{S3}\cdot v_3$$

that is

> $$_{S2}T_{S3}=(_{S1}T_{S2})^{-1}\cdot_{S1}T_{S3}$$

In the derivation I've assumed that:

- $_{S1}T_{S2}$ is the transition from $S_2$ to $S_1$
- $_{S1}T_{S3}$ is the transition from $S_3$ to $S_1$

Comment: Is multiplying a matrix by its inverse not the identity?

Comment: sorry I fix the typo!